# Android sdk. inflate menu(xml file) on button press

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-inflate

I understand that after Android 3 menu buttons are not supported. So, I simply want to use a buton on the screen to inflate the menu. I currently use an overridden

```
public boolean oncreateoptionsmenu(Menu menu) { MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate( R.menu.menu, menu); return true}.
```

This script runs on menu button press, but I also want it to run on my button press. How can this be done? What data is sent to the Menu parameter ( the menu to inflate to)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android 3+ the menu will be added to the actionbar automatically when the activity starts. There is no need to change anything.